# Show ruler on image hover and also zoom it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a Medical System which Doctors (users) can send ECG (eletrocardiogram) to other Doctors (specialists) and then this one, review it to help them. To review this ECG - which is a JPG image - they need a ruler to check if the "lines" of the ECG have "changes" or not.

An ECG image is like this > http://cdn.lifeinthefastlane.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/ecg_brugada_001.jpg

So, basically what I'm trying to achieve is when the user hover the image, I have to zoom it 20% more and also show a ruler to help him to make his analysis.

I was searching over internet and I couldn't find something similar in any other system :(

Someone has an idea how can I achieve this? Thanks!!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

I dont know about ruler, but I can give you idea about image zoom on hover

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="path_to_image" alt="pepsi" width="540" height="548">

</div>
```

**CSS3**

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  position: relative;

  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 540px;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;

  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I hope it will helps !!